# Vimium tab switching doesn't work at new(empty) tabs and tabs with error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

When I switch between tabs using shortcuts, sometimes Vimium (chrome
extension) stops switching and seems to be inactive (grey Vimium icon). It
usually happed when there is empty tab, tab with webpage error, or opened local
file from hdd

How to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Chrome doesn't load extensions on special pages.

For example, have a look at [this issue at vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/2568)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is problem anymore (may have been fixed). I use the extension [New Tab Redirect](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna) to redirect new tab to a new page which allows me to use Vimium.